# What's [] in [].forEach.call()

Tags: javascript

In the following code, I'm not sure what `[]` is supposed to represent. I'm assuming it just symbolizes the most recently declared array. Can anyone clarify?

```
var lists = [racersList, volunteersList];
[].forEach.call(lists, function(list) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Why don't you just do `lists.forEach(function(list), {...});`?

Comment: @Blender he's asking what the code does, so he didn't write it.

Comment: @Stijn: Maybe. A suggestion won't hurt.

Comment: Raymond, the question you linked answers my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

It's an empty array. It really doesn't matter what array it is; it just needs *some* array to get an array's `forEach` method. You could also use `Array.prototype.forEach` to get it directly rather than creating an empty array and digging `forEach` out of it.

This approach is usually used when you have an array-like object (like `NodeList`; has `length`, `0`, `1`, `2`, etc. properties) but is actually not an array. The array-like object doesn't have the array methods, but if you can get the array methods to run with the appropriate `this` (achieved with `call`), they will work nonetheless.

Since here you actually have a *real* array rather than an array-*like* object, you can invoke `forEach` directly, e.g., `lists.forEach(...)`.

Comment: In this case, "lists" *is* an array, so there's really no point.